# Show images on top for html css tab

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am using this css tab element. Current state when a tab is clicked content shows on the bottom. My goal is to get the content to show on the top instead of the bottom but am having trouble with how to do this. I want to show a different image on top instead of the bottom; I followed an earlier tutorial and got this far, but I ideally want to show all the content on top instead of the bottom; any direction would be great.

```css
            @import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #f6f9fa;
}

h1 {
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

/*Fun begins*/
.tab_container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

input, section {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

label {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4,
#tab5:checked ~ #content5 {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.tab_container .tab-content p,
.tab_container .tab-content h3 {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInScale 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: fadeInScale 0.7s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeInScale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.tab_container .tab-content h3  {
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_container [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #0CE;
}

.tab_container [id^="tab"]:checked + label .fa {
  color: #0CE;
}

label .fa {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
}

/*Media query*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  label span {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .tab_container {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

/*Content Animation*/
@keyframes fadeInScale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.no_wrap {
  text-align:center;
  color: #0ce;
}
.link {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tab_container">
            
            <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" >
            <label for="tab1"><i class="fa fa-code"></i><span>Code</span></label>
        
            <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
            <label for="tab2"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span>About</span></label>
        
            <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
            <label for="tab3"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Services</span></label>
        
            <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
            <label for="tab4"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i><span>Portfolio</span></label>
        
            <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
            <label for="tab5"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Contact</span></label>
        
            <section id="content1" class="tab-content">
                <h3>Headline 1</h3>
              
        
            </section>
        
            <section id="content2" class="tab-content">
              <h3>Headline 1</h3>
                
        
            </section>
        
            <section id="content3" class="tab-content">
                <h3>Headline 3</h3>
               
        
            </section>
        
            <section id="content4" class="tab-content">
                <h3>Headline 4</h3>
        
            </section>
        
            <section id="content5" class="tab-content">
                <h3>Headline 5</h3>
        
            </section>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redo the layout using CSS grid and keep your HTML code unchanged.

```css
.tab_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
}
section {
  grid-row-end: -2;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

Then you remove the use of float and the width defined for the label elements. I also inverted the border/box-shadow defined

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #f6f9fa;
}

h1 {
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}


/*Fun begins*/

.tab_container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
}
section {
  grid-row-end: -2;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

input,
section {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

label {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4,
#tab5:checked~#content5 {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-top: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.tab_container .tab-content p,
.tab_container .tab-content h3 {
  animation: fadeInScale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.tab_container .tab-content h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_container [id^="tab"]:checked+label {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #0CE;
}

.tab_container [id^="tab"]:checked+label .fa {
  color: #0CE;
}

label .fa {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
}


/*Media query*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  label span {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_container {
    width: 98%;
  }
}


/*Content Animation*/

@keyframes fadeInScale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.no_wrap {
  text-align: center;
  color: #0ce;
}

.link {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab_container">

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab1"><i class="fa fa-code"></i><span>Code</span></label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span>About</span></label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Services</span></label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i><span>Portfolio</span></label>

  <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Contact</span></label>

  <section id="content1" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Headline 1</h3>


  </section>

  <section id="content2" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Headline 1</h3>


  </section>

  <section id="content3" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Headline 3</h3>


  </section>

  <section id="content4" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Headline 4</h3>

  </section>

  <section id="content5" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Headline 5</h3>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Really great solution without upending the entire code. Appreciate your answer on this